# Google Sheets Formula for "If x cell = less than 100% AND y cell = date greater than one year ago then format row color to red

Tags: google-sheets

I have a training tracking spreadsheet for about 1000 people.

One of the requirements is that they meet all their training requirements in less than 12 months from the date of hire or promotion.

I have a column that calculates the percentage of their required training.

I have a column that shows their date of hire or promotion.

What I have no idea how to do is to correlate those two data sets so that I can use it as a "trigger" to highlight the row of the person who is overdue to red.
I know how to do it with one or the other, but for an IF THIS AND THIS THEN formula in Google Sheets I have no idea.

The closest I can think of is a custom formula in conditional formatting of:

```
=AND($BY2<1, $J2>Today-365)
```

But it won't work for me :(

Answer (score 0):

I think I got there by modifying an Excel formula I found with a similar subject.

```
=AND($H2<100%, $J2<(TODAY()-365))
```

That seemed to work for me.